# Integration with $\sin()$ and $\cos()$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I solve this integration problem?

$$
\int{\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)}\,dx}
$$

Comment: Do you have any details on any attempts you've made to solve the problem? What have you tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: One suggestion is to note that the denominator is $\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(2x)$, so we are integrating $4\csc^2(2x)$. This may be familiar, it involves $\cot$.

Comment: I was looking for the identities to solve the problem, but I did't note that the number one could be changed for sin2x+cos2x. So it counts for me.

Answer (score 8):

$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{1}{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}\,dx &= \int\frac{\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}\,dx\\
&= \int\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}\,dx+\int \frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\,dx\\
&= \int \sec^2 x\,dx+\int \csc^2 x\,dx \\
&= \tan x-\cot x+C
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it  :D

Answer (score 3):

Write $\sin^2 \cos^2 x=\frac14 \sin^2 2x$.  Then, we have

$$\int \frac{1}{\sin^2 \cos^2 x}\,dx=4 \int \csc^2 (2x)\,dx=-2\cot (2x)+C$$

Of course, we can use the identity $2\cot 2x =\cot x-\tan x$ to recover the result reported by @juantheron.

Comment: This doubles as a proof that $2\cot2x=\cot x-\tan x$ (at least, up to a constant).

Comment: @columbus8myhw Well, yes I suppose so.  But it is straightforward to show the identity directly - and then the constant is ambiguously $0$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, use $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$, then let $t=2x$, and finally write $\dfrac1{\sin t}=\dfrac{\sin t}{\sin^2t}=$ $=-\dfrac{\cos't}{1-\cos^2t}$